# Spring MVC exception for Could not resolve view with name where use 'redirect: " in controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I got some interesting problem with spring viewresolver

I have set-up simple spring mvc-thymeleaf application

spring-servlet.xml is as follows:

```
<mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**" />
  <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />


  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:component-scan base-package="thymeleafexamples.thvsjsp" />
  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="Messages" />
  </bean>


  <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="index,*th" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
  </bean>    

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="*jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="Messages" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="index,*th" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
  </bean>    

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="*jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
  </bean>

and web.xml as 

 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

when i use controller with reqestmapping as same of my jsp i.e. subscribejsp
redirect worked well but when i change controller requestmapping to 'subscribe'
it got error like

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'redirect: /subscribe' in servlet with name 'spring'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

My controller looks as belows:

```
@Controller
public class SubscribeJsp {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SubscribeJsp.class);


    public SubscribeJsp() {
        super();
    }




    @ModelAttribute("allTypes")
    public SubscriptionType[] populateTypes() {
        return new SubscriptionType[] { SubscriptionType.ALL_EMAILS, SubscriptionType.DAILY_DIGEST };
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/subscribe",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSubscription(final Subscription subscription) {
        return "subscribejsp";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/subscribesave", params={"save"})
    public String subscribe(final Subscription subscription, final BindingResult bindingResult, final ModelMap model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "subscribejsp";
        }
        log.info("JUST ADDED SUBSCRIPTION: " + subscription);
        model.clear();
        return "redirect:subscribe";
    }


}
```

Comment: i have used spring-webmvc dependency 3.2.3 and thymeleaft 2.13

Comment: Make sure you add your controller class path to component scan in spring-servlet.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute path for a redirection unless you are sure you really want to look for url relative to current path. So you you simply write your redirection that way :

```
return "redirect:/subscribe";
```

And you should remove the line

```
<property name="viewNames" value="*jsp" />
```

from the `InternalResourceViewResolver` in your `spring-servlet.xm` file. It blocks it from correctly finding *views* (including redirection ...) not ending in jsp and does not help in anything.

Comment: I have use that solution but i got same error in that case also

Comment: This controller works only when i change my requestmapping from subscribe to subscribejsp and change redirect:/subscribejsp

Comment: @kamlesh The other line to blame is `<property name="viewNames" value="*jsp" />` - post edited

Answer (score 0):

thanks Serge Ballesta, solution works by removing 
but i have used two different view resolvers one for jsp and for thymeleaf.
and i want them two works accordingly. Actually i do not want to kept jsp pages and
thymeleaf enabled html pages in two different folders neither i can't return two
view names as jsp/mypage.jsp or thymelef/th.html from my controller. Any suggestiong to
solve this problem.
 this will help in this situation but with this problem that i have to use same name for jsp and controller mapping names

Answer (score 0):

keep the:

```
<property name="viewNames" value="index,*th" />
```

delete the:

```
<property name="viewNames" value="*jsp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your return statement from `return "redirect:subscribe";` to `return "redirect:/subscribe";`